# References and Software Implementations for Multi-Response Modelling

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

Suppose you have some covariates X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 and you want to create a regression model where there are two response variables : Y1 and Y2.

In the past, I have approached this problem by creating two separate regression models:

**Y1 ~ f(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)**

**Y2 ~ f(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)**

However, now I am interested in learning about statistical models that can jointly model this data together, for example:

**P(Y1, Y2) ~ f(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)**

I think that this approach would allow for modelling potential correlation structures with Y1 and Y2.

**My Question:** Do such models exist that can jointly model multiple responses - is this a popular topic in statistics? Are there any standard references and software implementations (e.g. R programming language) for these kinds of models? The only thing I could find was the following : https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v084i04.

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate linear regression can be handled directly by the standard `lm()` function in R. As [Fox and Weisberg](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf) say (page 3):

> Multivariate linear models are fit in **R** with the `lm()` function. The procedure is the essence of simplicity: The left-hand side of the model is a matrix of responses, with each column representing a response variable and each row a case; the right-hand side of the model and all other arguments to lm are precisely the same as for a univariate linear model...

That reference illustrates how to use functions provided by the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) to simplify calculations and tests that take the outcome correlations into account.

Things aren't quite so simple with generalized linear models. The [`mcglm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mcglm) that you cite helps with such models.

Answer (score 0):

The topic of multivariate regression from a Bayesian semiparametric perspective is covered in this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/eprint/A9SCWXKJ39VAKJ3JPYZF/full?target=10.1080/10618600.2020.1739534). The R package BNSP  implements the methods, [link](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=BNSP). The function from BNSP for multivariate regression is `mvrm`.